# $S^{-1}B$ and $T^{-1}B$ isomorphic for $T=f(S)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules, fractions

> Let $f:A\to B$ be a homomorphism of rings, $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ and $T=f(S)$. Then $S^{-1}B$ and $T^{-1}B$ are isomorphic as $S^{-1}A$-modules.

First we define the obvious homomorphism $\phi:S^{-1}B\to T^{-1}B$ by $\frac{b}{s}\mapsto \frac{b}{f(s)}$. I can derive the facts that $\phi$ is a homomorphism as well as surjectivity, but I am unsure about injectivity.

Suppose $\frac{b}{f(s)}=\frac{0}{1}$, then $\exists\ t=f(s')\in T$ such that $tb=f(s')b=0$. And now I am stuck, because what I need is $s''b=0$ for some $s''\in S$, but $f(s')\in T$, so it doesn't really help me.

Comment: Hint: If $s \in S$ and $b \in B$, what does $sb$ mean?  How does it compare to $f(s)b$?

Comment: Use the universal properties in order to avoid any computations (have you checked that $\phi$ is well-defined? etc)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Since $S^{-1}B$ is an $S^{-1}A$ module we have $\frac{a}{s}\cdot\frac{b}{f(s')} := \frac{f(a)b}{f(s)f(s')}$ and especially $sb=\frac{s}{1}\frac{b}{1}=\frac{f(s)b}{1}=f(s)b$ for any $s\in S, b\in B$. So in our case, $f(s')b=0$ just means $f(s')b=s'b=0$, which shows injectivity ?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: If you don't mind me asking, how would one go about solving this using the universal property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Injectivity.** Let $\frac{r_1}{s_1},\frac{r_2}{s_2}\in S^{-1}B$, and suppose 
that
\begin{align*}
\phi\left(\frac{r_1}{s_1}\right)&=\phi\left(\frac{r_2}{s_2}\right) \\
\frac{r_1}{f(s_1)}&=\frac{r_2}{f(s_2)}
\end{align*}
So $\exists$ $t\in T$ such that
\begin{equation*}
t\left(f(s_2)r_1-f(s_1)r_2\right)=0
\end{equation*}
Since $t\in T=f(S)$, $\exists$ $s\in S$ such that $f(s)=t$, and
\begin{align*}
f(s)\left(f(s_2)r_1-f(s_1)r_2\right)&=0
\end{align*}
Since $B$ is an $A$ module via $f$
\begin{equation*}
s\cdot (s_2\cdot r_1-s_1\cdot r_2)=0
\end{equation*}
and thus $\frac{r_1}{s_1}=\frac{r_2}{s_2}$. So 
$\operatorname{ker}(\phi)=0$.

Comment: The line "Since $B$ is an $A$ module via $f$" opened my eyes. Now I understood it.

Comment: Thomas: That is indeed the key here.